# How to define a custom sbt setting in project/{...}.scala?

Tags: scala, sbt

Using **sbt 1.0.1** and **scala 2.12.3**...

My directory structure:

```
project/build.properties
project/PackageDist.scala
src/main/scala/{$packageDirs}/MyClass.scala
build.sbt
```

In **project/PackageDist.scala** , I've got:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import io.RichFile._

import java.io.File

object PackageDist {
  lazy val distArtifactRoot = settingKey[File]("The directory to which all distribution artifacts will be written")
  lazy val distDirectoryName = settingKey[String]("The name of the root diectory for the distribution")

  def distArtifactRootFile : Setting[File] = 
    distArtifactRoot := target.value / "dist"
  def distDirectory : Setting[String] =
    distDirectoryName := s"${normalizedName.value}-${version.value}"
}
```

In **build.sbt** , I've got:

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  organization := "myTestOrg",
  scalaVersion := "2.12.3",
  version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
)

lazy val root = ( project in file(".") )
  .settings(
    name := "package-test",
    commonSettings
  )
```

When I run `sbt` , the `distArtifactRoot` and `distDirectoryName` settings are not available when I run `> settings -V`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your settings visible to other sbt files:

```
object PackageDist {
  lazy val distArtifactRoot = settingKey[File](
    "The directory to which all distribution artifacts will be written")
  lazy val distDirectoryName =
    settingKey[String]("The name of the root diectory for the distribution")

  val settings = Seq(
    distArtifactRoot := target.value / "dist",
    distDirectoryName := s"${normalizedName.value}-${version.value}"
  )
}
```

Then you use them in any project like

```
lazy val root = ( project in file(".") )
  .settings(PackageDist.settings: _*) // <-- Add the settings to this project
  .settings(
    name := "package-test",
  )
```

Reloading sbt and typing `dist` +  make the autocomplete suggest the 2 settings you added.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe someday, this can be added to the official documentation. Incidentally, how did you figure it out?

Comment: By studing [this documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Basic-Def.html)

Comment: I can see how you got there, but I was already very familiar with that page, and still your solution was non-obvious to me. That's why I'm curious about how the community pieces together such things. I got into the predicament of my question by following this tutorial:
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6CnYQDL9Eg.

Comment: Documentation is not where sbt shines. Things are almost never explicit and we need to infer them. But this is just my personal opinion.

Comment: Thanks again! I still spent four hours swearing at the compiler, but without your help, it would have been double that time.